# Can't delete instance of entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using visual studio 2013 and i am using entity framework to develop project.

I want to delete an instance of entity.

this is my entity :

```
INOTESTEntities db = new INOTESTEntities();

var finaExam = db.classAssesmentDateInfo.Where(x => x.Id == 22).First();
```

when i want to delete it i am trying `db.DeleteObject(finaExam );`

but `DeleteObject` doesnt exist so i cant delete it. Can you help me ?.

Comment: Use `db.classAssessmentDateInfo.DeleteObject(finaExam)` followed by `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: why doesnt exist deleteObject method ? i used before many times but now i cant , where i am missing at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using DbContext, you need to cast to ObjectContext to use the DeleteObject method.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.DeleteObject(finaExam);
```

If you want to use DbContext directly without a cast, use the Remove syntax:

```
db.classAssessmentDateInfo.Remove(finaExam);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Remove marks the entity as Deleted.  When SaveChanges is called, the marked entity generates a delete query.

Finally, if you are using VS 2013, your project has most likely included EF 5 or 6 (my vote is on 6), which defaults to DbContext instead of the now "deprecated" ObjectContext. This is why syntax you have used in the past no longer works in your new project.

Comment: in order to i use VS2013 i cant use deleteObject i must use remove is it true.

Comment: No, you can cast your context to IObjectContextAdapter as shown above.  However, there's really no advantage to that over using Remove and it may confuse other contributors to your project.  Also, keep in mind that the context chosen is related to the Entity Framework used.  You CAN revert your project to an old ObjectContext template, although there's no advantage to that either.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` instead of the older `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`, in which case you would need to call `Remove()` on the DbSet:

```
db.classAssesmentDateInfo.Remove(finaExam);
```